# prettier --write found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.-how can I resolve these errors?

Tags: prettier

I am new to git and cypress. We also use circleCI. When I am trying to commit, I am getting these errors, and dont know how to fix them..are the errors in the files pointed out by "error"?

```
✖ prettier --write found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
.eslintrc.js 54ms
README.md 91ms
cypress.json 9ms
cypress/integration/SaveFormTest.js 49ms
cypress/integration/SaveFormTest_orig.js 20ms
cypress/support/commands.js 19ms

cypress_original.json 5ms
jest.config.js 7ms
src/api/requests.js 29ms
src/components/FileUploadTile/FileUploadTile.js 25ms
src/components/FileUploadTile/UploadButton/UploadButton.js 11ms
src/components/TopPanel/TopPanel.js 32ms
src/config/messages/en.js 9ms
src/constants/constants.js 13ms
src/containers/UserWidget/UserWidget.js 47ms
src/pages/LoginPage/LoginPage.js 30ms
src/pages/MainPage/MainPage.test.js 20ms
src/pages/TrainingQueuePages/TrainingQueueDashboardPage/ActionButtons/ActionButtons.js 15ms
src/pages/TrainingQueuePages/TrainingQueueDashboardPage/TrainingQueueList/RecordTile/RecordTile.js 18ms
src/pages/TrainingQueuePages/TrainingQueueDashboardPage/TrainingQueueList/RecordTile/RecordTile.test.js 17ms
src/store/trainingQueueDashboard/actions.js 17ms
src/store/trainingQueueDashboard/actions.test.js 34ms
src/store/trainingQueueDashboard/reducers.js 17ms
src/store/trainingQueueDashboard/reducers.test.js 32ms
src/store/user/constants.js 5ms
src/store/user/reducers.js 14ms
src/store/user/reducers.test.js 23ms
[error] cypress_old.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:7)
[error] > 1 | b0VIM 8.1��B^.�rrenukaalurkarRenukas-MBP~renukaalurkar/Documents/cypress_tests_renuka/KW-Offers-FE/cypress.jsonutf-8
[error]     |       ^
[error]   2 | U3210#"! Utpada������w\E$������} "defau}} "defaultCommandTimeout": 100000 },      "test_admin_pass":${TEST_ADMIN_PASS}   "test_admin":${TEST_ADMIN},      "test_tc_pass":${TEST_TC_PASS}, "test_tc":${TEST_TC},   "test_pass":${TEST_PASS},       "test_user":${TEST_USER},       "password":${PASSWORD}, "user_name",    "host":"https://app.kw-offers.master.kw-offers-dev.com/",  "env":{{
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

Comment: You have a lot going on. I see husky, pre-commit hooks and so on. It seems like there are some test cases set up and those are failing. Maybe your code has issues? Check with your company policies on commit rules.

Comment: Have you looked further into the actual error message? i.e. there is a message for SyntaxError in `cypress_old.json`. Start there. Prettier apparently doesn't like somethingin that (Unexpected token on line 1, character 7). The printout doesn't look like json... P.S. this doesn't have anything to do with Git or CircleCI.